# Why do I get error "declaration as array of references" when I use the reference operator without parentheses in a 2D array parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters

I understand C++ passes arrays by reference even if we don't use the reference operator (&), but since it can be added with no harm (I think), I'm curious as to why this code throws

> declaration of 'matrix' as array of references

```
void function (int &matrix[2][5])  {
    //something
}

int main()  {
    int matrix[2][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
    function(matrix);
}
```

while adding parentheses in `(&matrix)` works:

```
void function (int (&matrix)[2][5])  {
    //something
}
```

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Because two different syntax mean two completely different things? Reference to array of ints != array of int references.

Comment: *"I understand C++ passes arrays by reference"* it doesn't

Comment: C++ does not pass arrays as references.

Comment: Arrays are not passed to functions at all; a pointer to the first element is passed instead.

Comment: Doesn't C++ pass a reference to the first element of the array? How is that different from "passing an array by reference"? Or it's just a matter of wording?

Comment: No. Pointers are ultimately different concept than references. You may want to check [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @Floella While you *could* say, in everyday English, that a pointer ”refers to” an object, that’s not what ”reference” means in C++. A pointer is not a reference, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&matrix[2][5]` has a different meaning from 
`(&matrix)[2][5])`.

The former means `matrix` is a *two dimensional array of references to int* and the latter means `matrix` is a reference to a *two dimensional array of integers*.

Since `matrix` is defined as a two dimensional array in `main`, the second form succeeds.

The [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/) tool can be helpful here:

```
int (&matrix)[2][5] - declare matrix as reference to array 2 of array 5 of int
int &matrix[2][5] - declare matrix as array 2 of array 5 of reference to int
```

Answer (score 2):

> I understand C++ passes arrays by reference even if we don't use the reference operator (&)

This is incorrect. C++ doesn't pass arrays as references. Additionally, there is no such thing as a "reference operator".

---

> I'm curious as to why this code throws

The code is not "throwing", that term is used in the context of exceptions. You are simply getting a compilation error, as you're attempting to define an array of references to integers.

This happens because

```
int &matrix[2][5]
```

is grouped as

```
int &((matrix[2])[5])
```

by default. Adding parenthesis makes the compiler parse your type as "reference to an array of integers".

Comment: No, it's grouped as `&((matrix[2])[5])` because `[]` has higher precedence than `&`.

Comment: Thanks. English not being my native tongue, I chose the word "throws" in the wrong context, although I see there are no exeptions anywhere on my code. About the & operator, I've always called it "reference operator" as it gets you a reference. So how exactly is this operator called? Thanks.

Comment: It's not an operator, operators are just "functions" with special syntax. This is part of the declaration syntax for references, I'm not sure if it has a particular name apart from... reference?

Comment: @Floella `&` in declarations is very different from `&` in expressions. In declarations it means "reference", but as an operator in expressions it means "address of" (or "pointer to"). Blame the C++ designers for the inconsistency.